# Java Mail Reading using spring mail adapter inconsistent behaviour

Tags: jakarta-mail, spring-integration

I am using spring 3.0.6 and spring integration 2.0.3. If I mark the email as unread or if I receive new email many times the adapter is not reading it. I am not sure if it is issue with IMAP server or with API. Below is the debug log for same.

```
    { DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
2013-01-16 11:58:00,232 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver - connecting to store [imap://username:*****@IMAP server IP:143/Inbox]
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "IMAP server IP", port 143, isSSL false
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. BURCA1
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN STARTTLS IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=IMAP server IP, user=username, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN STARTTLS IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: NTLM
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: GSSAPI
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
A3 LIST "" Inbox
* LIST (\Marked \HasChildren) "/" INBOX
A3 OK LIST completed.
2013-01-16 11:58:00,488 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver - opening folder [imap://username:*****@IMAP server IP:143/Inbox]
DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
A4 SELECT INBOX
* 26 EXISTS
*** 0 RECENT**
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 5298] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 213] The next unique identifier value
A4 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
2013-01-16 11:58:00,553 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
A5 SEARCH UNANSWERED UNDELETED NOT (SEEN) ALL
* SEARCH
A5 OK SEARCH completed.
2013-01-16 11:58:00,590 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver - found 0 new messages
A6 EXAMINE INBOX
* 26 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Permanent flags
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 5298] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 213] The next unique identifier value
A6 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed.
A7 CLOSE
A7 OK CLOSE completed.
DEBUG: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The protocol trace clearly shows that the server thinks you have no "recent" messages, as well as no messages that are both unanswered and unseen (and not deleted).  If you check each message individually, do you find any such messages?

Comment: Hi Bill, If I see the mailbox again all the unread messages are shown as read in outlook web client but the adapter sees no new/unread messages. I am not sure if I correctly understood your question. Thanks!

Comment: Turn on DEBUG level logging for org.springframework.integration - it should provide you with more insight.

Comment: Another question...  When you say "many times the adapter is not seeing it", does that mean that sometimes it works as you expect and sometimes it does not?  If so, do you have another client (Outlook, etc.) using the same mailbox?  That other client might be marking the messages as read before you get a chance to see them.

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable comments which guided me to figure out where exactly the problem was. As you mentioned Bill, it turned out that the other applications listener was also listening to same mailbox and reading the new emails and that's why very few times it worked.When I tried with different email account it is working without any issues. Thanks again!

Comment: Here is the debug log again, this time UNSEEN message is discovered though it is not recent one. DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
A4 SELECT INBOX
* 159 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
* OK [UNSEEN 158] Is the first unseen message

Comment: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 4180] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 174] The next unique identifier value
A4 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
2013-01-17 11:47:00,500 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
A5 SEARCH UNANSWERED UNDELETED NOT (SEEN) ALL * SEARCH 158
A5 OK SEARCH completed.
2013-01-17 11:47:00,568 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver - found 1 new messages